# Как получить ссылку на balloon layout и object layout из события mouseleave

Tags: javascript, события, yandex-maps-jsapi, layout, mouse-event

Вешаю на балун объекта яндекс карты событие mouseleave. Как получить доступ на ноду балуна и самого объекта на карте в dom из evt?

```
objectManager.objects.balloon.events.add(
'mouseleave',
function(evt) {
```

Когда вешаю событие на сам объект, то в evt есть sourceEvent, через него получается добраться до ноды объекта. А вот у балуна нет sourceEvent.

Хочу на выход курсора из балуна поиграться со стилями layout объекта на карте и layout самого балуна.

Comment: Какие карты имеете ввиду?)

Comment: Яндекс карты, теги не добавил.